# USB tethering not working properly

Tags: settings

I'm using one plus two. I tried everything but still the option 'USB tethering - USB not connected' is like this and I'm not able to able or disable it, it's Grey.... Please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is a checklist of what you need:

- Is the cable you are using the official one that came with the phone?
  Some third party cables are untrustworty
- Is your computer's USB socket working correctly and transferring
  data? You can check this by plugging in a simple USB flash drive. This is the most likely problem because android should enable this option as soon as it detects it is connected to a computer.